# How to use color hex values as a function argument in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, user-defined-functions

I am creating a plot with a user defined function and passing color as an option. It's working fine by using `as_label` or `quo_name` with **colors by name** for example **grey** or **pink**.

But when I pass **hex codes** then it **fails** even if I pass just alpha numerical value without # still it doesn't make that as string.

small example:

```
udf_tax_rev_plot <- function(background_line_color = grey){
  
  background_line_color = enquo(background_line_color)
  
  print(as_label(background_line_color) )
}

udf_tax_rev_plot(33ffff) 

##### output ##### 
Error: unexpected symbol in "udf_tax_rev_plot(33ffff"
```

**Actual plot code**:

```
udf_tax_rev_plot <- function(background_line_color = grey){
  
  background_line_color = enquo(background_line_color)

  tax_rev %>% 
    mutate(highlight_type = case_when(country %in%
                                   c("India","Singapore","Malaysia","Norway",
                                     "Denmark","United States","United Kingdom","China") ~ "Yes",
                                 TRUE ~ "No")) %>%
  ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(x = year, y = round(tax_revnue_perc_of_gdp,2), col = country), size = 1.1) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 1980, to = 2020, by = 5)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = label_dollar(prefix = "", suffix = " %"),
                       breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 60, by = 5)) +
    gghighlight(highlight_type == "Yes",
                unhighlighted_params = list(size = 1, colour = alpha(as_label(background_line_color), 0.4))) +
    facet_wrap(~continent) +
    theme_viny_bright() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)
            ) +
    labs(title = "Total Tax Revenue earned % of GDP for world countries across time",
         subtitle = "created by ViSa",
         caption = "Data Source: Gapminder",
         y = "Total Tax Revenue % of GDP" 
         )
}

udf_tax_rev_plot(#33ffff)
```

How do I fix this ?

**UPDATE**

Here is the code with gapminder data to reproduce

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(gghighlight)
library(gapminder)

udf_tax_rev_plot <- function(background_line_color = grey){
  
  background_line_color = enquo(background_line_color)

  gapminder %>% 
    mutate(highlight_type = case_when(country %in%
                                   c("India","Singapore","Malaysia","Norway",
                                     "Denmark","United States","United Kingdom","China") ~ "Yes",
                                 TRUE ~ "No")) %>%
  ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(x = year, y = round(gdpPercap,2), col = country), size = 1.1) +
    #scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 1980, to = 2020, by = 5)) +
    #scale_y_continuous(labels = label_dollar(prefix = "", suffix = " %"),
                       #breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 60, by = 5)) +
    gghighlight(highlight_type == "Yes",
                unhighlighted_params = list(size = 1, colour = alpha(as_label(background_line_color), 0.4))) +
    facet_wrap(~continent) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)
            ) +
    labs(title = "Total Tax Revenue earned % of GDP for world countries across time",
         subtitle = "created by ViSa",
         caption = "Data Source: Gapminder",
         y = "Total Tax Revenue % of GDP" 
         )
}

udf_tax_rev_plot(pink)
```

Comment: You can't pass unquoted variables if they begin with a # or a number. The user will have to use double or single quotes

Comment: @AllanCameron oh ...I tried passing hex in quotes `udf_tax_rev_plot("#33ffff")` using same code but it gives errors. I guess I will have to modify it to handle both `"hex color"` and `color_name`. But this is odd.

Comment: Yeah, long story short, no reason to use `enquo()` here. Just pass in the color as character and use it as such within the function.

Comment: Yeah @Adam, I agree but I was thinking of passing color name as it is without quotes and hex with or without quotes whichever possible but i guess that is not an easy option so will keep it simple with the way you mentioned!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for the data you have provided:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(gghighlight)
library(gapminder)

udf_tax_rev_plot <- function(background_line_color = "grey"){
  
  
  gapminder %>% 
    mutate(highlight_type = case_when(country %in%
                                        c("India","Singapore","Malaysia","Norway",
                                          "Denmark","United States","United Kingdom","China") ~ "Yes",
                                      TRUE ~ "No")) %>%
    ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(x = year, y = round(gdpPercap,2), col = country), size = 1.1) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 1980, to = 2020, by = 5)) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = label_dollar(prefix = "", suffix = " %"),
                       breaks = seq(from = 0, to = 60, by = 5)) +
    gghighlight(highlight_type == "Yes",
                unhighlighted_params = list(size = 1, colour = alpha(background_line_color, 0.4))) +
    facet_wrap(~continent) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)
    ) +
    labs(title = "Total Tax Revenue earned % of GDP for world countries across time",
         subtitle = "created by ViSa",
         caption = "Data Source: Gapminder",
         y = "Total Tax Revenue % of GDP" 
    )
}

udf_tax_rev_plot("pink")
```

You have to provide the color as a character string.

- So either like this: `udf_tax_rev_plot("#33ffff")`
- Or like this: `udf_tax_rev_plot('#33ffff')`

Comment: `udf_tax_rev_plot("#33ffff")` is giving an error: `Error: Unknown colour name: "#33ffff"`. I will try to put above code with gapminder data so that it can be replicated

Comment: can you share a sample dataframe? This would make it easier to find the issue

Comment: I updated my answer. It seems to work. Make sure you do not use `enquo` and also not `as_label`.

Comment: I have updated original post with gapminder data but I will try implement with your updated code. Thanks alot!!!